# cpp 2d vector arguments (size, ?)?

Tags: c++, vector, parameters

I came across this line in `reachability.cpp` in assignment 1 of Algorithms on Graphs on Coursera where `n` is num vertices and `m` is num edges from `cin`.

```
vector<vector<int> > adj(n, vector<int>());
```

What is that second argument?  I think this makes a 2D vector with `n` rows, each having a `vector(int)` but none of the other answers on here mention the second argument and I couldn't find anything on cpp reference and other sources.

I tried to explicity state the size of the columns and initialize with 0 like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > adj(n, vector<int>(n, 0));
```

because I wanted to print out the shape with the function below to confirm that I have an adjacency matrix.

```
void print(vector<vector<int> >  &a)
{
  std::cout<<"Vec elements:\n";

  for(unsigned int j =0; j<a.size(); j++)
  {
    for(unsigned int k =0; k<a[j].size(); k++)
    {
      std::cout<<a[k][j]<<" ";
    }
  }
}
```

I have other code where I just make a 2D vector like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > graph;
```

Then I resize each row to have `n` columns with a loop to make the adjacency matrix.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  graph[i].resize(n); //resize 2d array
```

Because this is boilerplate code provided by the instructors, there must be some merit to what they are doing.  So I'd like to know what it is.

Edit:

Saw this in Gaddis' book:

[image: Gaddis vectors]

So I guess it is making a vector of `n` elements with each element being a `vector<int>`.

Comment: [This `std::vector` constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) should hopefully be helpful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I took C++ in school 2 years ago, switched to Java then Python and now it seems I have to start over with Gaddis's textbook.  Though we never covered vectors but rather used arrays.

Comment: "I couldn't find anything on cpp reference"  try this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector (overload 2)

Comment: vectors are one of the main STL containers, I'd recommend *really* getting familiar with it, as that's one of the main benefits of C++. I'd imagine that the class was trying to teach C and C++ together, so they never got to vectors. Either that or they were teaching C++98...

Comment: I concur with the above. With the possible exception of `std::string`, you'll find the most-often used class template in your C++ arsenal will be `std::vector`, and as such it deserves extra study time. Fwiw, in your first example, that second argument is pointless. If omitted, the vector will use default construction for the `n` elements, which is exactly what `std::vector<int>()` provides as a temporary copy src. It is more suitable to see this constructor when default construction is *not* sufficient (eg. your second example), or even possible (such as a type with no default ctor).

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I apologize for that oversight.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I guess they wanted to make it super-explicit?

Comment: @YSC That helps alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is that second argument? I think this makes a 2D vector with n rows, each having a vector(int)

Yes, that's right.

The second argument is the "initial value" for each element of your [outer] vector. Here you're saying that each element, which is in turn a `vector<int>`, will simply be default-constructed. (Well, copy constructed from this default-constructed temporary!)

---

Note that, contrary to the claims in the other answer, the constructor you're using is *not* `vector( const vector& other, const Allocator& alloc )`, but `vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())` (with the third argument left as its default). This question has nothing whatsoever to do with allocators.

It is true, however, that you could also have used `explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() )` and relied on default-construction of the inner vectors:

```
vector<vector<int> > adj(n);
```

Comment: @Lightning someone said in the comments that it isn't really necessary in the first example I raised in the question but in the second example it would be.  The book had the first so I'm guessing they wanted it extra-explicit for teaching purposes.

Comment: @mLstudent33 Yep, makes sense.